# Understanding constraint in generics

Tags: typescript

```js
type Format = "rawline" | "keyvalue"

class KeyValues {}
class RawLines {}

type TypeByFormat<F extends Format> = F extends "keyvalue"
  ? KeyValues
  : F extends "rawline"
  ? RawLines
  : undefined;


function createSectionContent<F extends Format>(
  format: F
): TypeByFormat<F> | undefined {
  switch (format) {
    case "keyvalue": {
      const c : F = "keyvalue"
      return new KeyValues();
    }
    case "rawline":
      return new RawLines(raw);
    default:
      return undefined;
  }
}
```

gives me

```
Type '"keyvalue"' is not assignable to type 'F'.
  '"keyvalue"' is assignable to the constraint of type 'F', but 'F' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Format'.(2322)
```

I don't understand what I miss here.
I know that for this example I don't need generics, but in my project, I must use `F` to create a conditional type for the return value.

Comment: How can this work when called as `foo<"rawline">("rawline")`? The line `const c: "rawline" = "keyvalue"` is wrong in that case. Which is what the error message it trying to say: "*'F' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Format'*"

Comment: Ok, I over-simplified my example, I will put the more complete example

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads

Comment: my goal was precisely to avoid to write an overload by value for `format`

Comment: Without something like [ms/TS#33014](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014) you won't get this to work as desired. You can refactor to generic indexed access like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wjDavm) shows.  Does that fully address your question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: that's a great answer! Thanks jcalz. One curiosity question though, why chose `interface` and not `type` for TypeByFormat?